# Is the Ideal gas approximation still valid if I have sizeable dynamic pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

Say, if I have a hose blowing or sucking air into/outo a bigger compartment, can I still regard the static preassure as obeying ideal gas law?

Comment: At room temperature (or higher) the errors are insignificant if the pressure is less than about 100 atmospheres, and only about 10% at 300 atmospheres. At lower temperatures (closer to the boiling point of liquid air) the errors are bigger at lower pressures.

Comment: Locally, the isotropic part of the compress stress tensor (which we call static pressure) comes close to satisfying the ideal gas law.  However, if the gas deformation is extremely rapid, the static pressure depends not only on the specific volume and temperature but also on the local rate of volume change.